# Dynamic generation ForeignKey fields on admin page django

Tags: python, autocomplete, django-admin

I have models:

```
class CompanyInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя компании',max_length=250)


class Staff(models.Model):
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(CompanyInfo)
    date = models.DateField( )
    name = models.CharField( max_length=30, )

class Relation(models.Model):
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(CompanyInfo)
    who = models.ForeignKey(Staff, related_name="who")
    with_whom = models.ForeignKey(Staff, related_name="with_whom")
    info = models.CharField( max_length=30, )
```

How I can create dynamic generation fields for `WHO` and `WITH_WHOM` form element on the admin-page? I chose `COMPANY_NAME`, and fields `WHO` and `WITH_WHOM` that show only people from that company.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate in a bit more detail on what you mean by *dynamic generation fields*? Otherwise, I'm afraid it's a bit difficult to help you because it's not really clear what your problem is.

Besides that, let me tell you that your model design is rather odd, especially your `Relation` model. If you want to establish a many-to-one relationship between two instances of the same model (I think that's what you are trying to accomplish here), then you should write it like that and get rid of your `Relation` model:

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    with_whom = models.ForeignKey('self')
```